# Xamarin Forms: System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in Android.Runtime.AndroidTypeManager:RegisterNativeMembers

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm getting the following exception while building my Xamarin Forms app in release mode:

```
[GraphicsEnvironment] Neither updatable production driver nor prerelease driver is supported.
[NetworkSecurityConfig] No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
[NetworkSecurityConfig] No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
[MultiDex] VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
[MultiDex] Installing application
[MultiDex] VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
[monodroid-gc] GREF GC Threshold: 46080
[CompatibilityChangeReporter] Compat change id reported: 183155436; UID 10158; state: ENABLED
[FirebaseApp] Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
[FirebaseInitProvider] FirebaseApp initialization successful
[mono-rt] [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in Android.Runtime.AndroidTypeManager:RegisterNativeMembers (Java.Interop.JniType,System.Type,System.ReadOnlySpan`1<char>): IL_0240: stloc.s   19
[mono-rt] 
[mono-rt] 
[mono-rt]   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.RegisterJniNatives (System.IntPtr typeName_ptr, System.Int32 typeName_len, System.IntPtr jniClass, System.IntPtr methods_ptr, System.Int32 methods_len) [0x00088] in <7685f94735ec4635bcf7c23732e3db0f>:0
```

Application while deploying in release mode stuck on splash screen.

XF version: 5.0.0.2545

Visual studio MAC 17.4.1

Referred this [thread](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/6480), but didn't help.

Comment: Does the build in release mode work if you try to create a new project?

Comment: since the app is following shared project approach. Current visual studio doesn't allow creating shared project approach.

Comment: Did you add a breakpoint in MainActivity OnCreate and does it hit? Have you tried removing `<EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>true</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>` in your .csproj